# Why does Ubuntu (Source) installation's rosdep skip some keys

Tags: ros, ros2, installation, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While following the [Ubuntu (Source) installation](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html), in the [Install dependencies using rosdep](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html#install-dependencies-using-rosdep) step, some rosdep keys are skipped as following:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -y --skip-keys "fastcdr rti-connext-dds-6.0.1 urdfdom_headers"
```

What is the reason for skipping these keys? I have gone back through the commit history of the tutorials back to ROS2 crystal, but these keys have existed before that time. I am wondering if the instructions are outdated.

The only logical explanation I can think of, for `rti-connext-dds-6.0.1`, is that it's not used as the default dds, and the size of the package is significant (154mb).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402748/why-does-ubuntu-(source)-installation%27s-rosdep-skip-some-keys/) by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2022-06-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-06-27**:
IIRC, Connext requires a license, which many people may not have, nor is it a default RMW implementation.

`fastcdr` is likely already included as a dependency of FastDDS (but this is speculation).

`urdfdom_headers` I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Connext is skipped because it needs a license to run so most people won't want to take the time to build it if they can't run it. Instructions for installing it directly are below.

`urdfdom_headers` and `fastcdr` are skipped because they do not provide a package.xml in their installed targets so rosdep via catkin_pkg doesn't detect that they've been installed, even if they've been installed or are in the workspace.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2022-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1